# Moving namespace block causes namespace not found

Tags: c#, namespaces, visual-studio-2013

I have an MVC 4.0 app (holding 76 projects).

I started some refactoring by moving usings blocks above each namespace declaration and put the using block under the namespace declaration. This is a common practice, stated by StyleCop.

Suddenly some referenced namespaces cannot be found, even in the same assembly!

(I checked if all the 76 projects target the .NET 4.0 framework, and that is).

(edit)
Small update: I seems that Visual Studio extends the referenced namespace.
This original code leads to a namespace missing:

```
namespace Progis.Kim.Application.UI.Controllers
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Progis.Kim.Application.UI.Support; 
}
```

But when using this code, VS can see it:

```
namespace Progis.Kim.Application.UI.Controllers
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Support;
}
```

It seems that VS concatenates the usings with the default namespace...

Comment: If you have a namespace hierarchy like `A.B.System.C` and move `using System.D;` from outside of the `namespace A.B` declaration to inside, I believe it is then an attempt to reference `A.B.System.D` rather than `global::System.D`

Comment: Damien, the issue is that the using holds one namespace that cannot be found, in the same assembly...

Comment: As I was trying to say, I'd be looking elsewhere in the project for any potential naming clashes, such that when the `using` was outside of the namespace, it was obviously using a fully-qualified namespace name, but now that it's inside the namespace, the first part of the name is matching something more local to the namespace.

Comment: Can you provide details?

Comment: I have 17 solution folders in the web app. One of them is Controllers. One specific controller had usings outside the namespace. I moved them inside the namespace and suddenly 5 or 6 of those usings where not recognized anymore. When using Intellisense the only solution found is 'Controllers'....

Comment: And if you prefix those `using`s with [`global::`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx), does it fix the issue?

Comment: It is fixed, by taking the usings as stated in the last edit, but I don't get the rationale.

Comment: And there's definitely nothing called `Progis` nested *within* the `Progis.Kim.Application.UI.Controllers` namespace?

Comment: @Damien: no, there is nothing nested there.